# Where would primitive settlements first start to occur outside of the middle-east and turkey?

Tags: natural-resources, prehistoric-times

Say when people as nomads, and started to form settlements with other people, where would these primitive settlements first started to appear, they would have first started to settle in regions around Israel and Turkey. My question is, where would they have settlements have appeared next, in areas not around the latter, and what reasons would they have for settling here, e.g. fertile lands for crops, natural defences like a hill and large quantities of natural resources, e.g. wood and clay?
I would assume rivers and/or places with access to the ocean, but did they have sufficient technology for sea-faring vessels for settling near the ocean viable?

Comment: this sounds a lot like a history question than a worldbuilding one. try asking these questions on the history stack.

Comment: Agriculture was invented a *very long time* after humans (both Neanderthals and then anatomically moderns) went on to populate the entire Old World. The requirement for fertile lands for crops is anachronistic by many many millennia. As for wood, the entire western and central Europe was forested in those days; wood was a non-issue. As for clay, I don't know, isn't it available just about everywhere? P.S. They settled near the sea simply because of the fish and shell-fish, not because they had ships to navigate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a history question concerning the real world and it should be migrated to [history.se].

Comment: Definitely history. Nomads would have been able to go to sea with just a little larger technology that they used to cross the large rivers. We know they crossed the rivers and got to Australia very shortly after leaving Africa. Lash several logs together and start paddling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening: *"where would these primitive settlements first started to appear, they would have first started to settle in regions around Israel and Turkey. My question is, where would they have settlements have appeared next"*

Agree with John's comment this is a historical (archeological) question rather than worldbuilding.

The notion agriculture was spread exclusively into the Middle East and then from the Middle East to Europe and the rest of the world is a viewpoint institutionalized by religions, in creation mythology: all three Abrahamistic religions locate God's creation in the Middle East, at the time agriculture spread there.

Agriculture development in Anatolia by far preceeded agriculture in the Middle East and Europe. Modern genetic research indicates [Anatolian farmers migrated everywhere](https://www.pnas.org/content/113/25/6886) to spread their habits, for several thousands of years.

Early spread of agriculture by Anatolians included [Egypt (8000-6000BC)](https://www.worldhistory.org/article/997/ancient-egyptian-agriculture/), with the great conditions along Jordan and Nile rivers. It reached [pre-Minoan Crete (about 7000BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minoan_civilization#Early_Minoan) and from the Aegean, it spread west.

Some regions like [Northern India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_agriculture_in_the_Indian_subcontinent) received the Anatolian farmer immigration earlier: around 9000BC-8000BC, an Anatolian-like agriculture developed in Northern India, about the same time agriculture started in Egypt.

Anatolians invented agriculture, but it was invented elsewhere also: they did not have to teach Chinese or Vietnamese how to do their agriculture.. Around 8000 BC, the [Chinese started agricultural development](https://www.britannica.com/topic/agriculture/Tools-and-techniques).